# Slide horizontal menu for Windows mobile 7 /8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Hello everyone i am trying to build a horizontal slide menu for a windows mobile 7 app. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: More details on what that menu would look like would be helpful.

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-mobile-create-a-sliding-menu-for-ios/

Answer (score 0):

That sliding menu is called *Navigation Drawer* and is a standard UI element for Android OS. It is not recommended on Windows Phone. However, you can mimic it using an offscreen `UserControl` or `Panel`.

Take a look at the following blog post: [A behavior to implement a scroll-into-view panel (for a Facebook-like GUI) on Windows Phone](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2013/09/a-behavior-to-implement-scroll-into.html).